# Recurring Tasks Org-mode

Tags: org-mode

I am trying to use `org-mode` for scheduling tasks with a time with no avail. Every time I set it the task is not repeated:

On my task I use `C-c C-d` and then type in `2015-09-15 9:00AM-11:00AM +1w`.

Is something with my formatting wrong or am I missing something bigger?

Comment: I'm on emacs 24.5 and the repeater is working for me.  Maybe should should need to view the agenda for the whole month

Comment: Sorry: Maybe  you  need to view the agenda for the whole month to see the repeater in action? With typing `C-c a a v m`

Comment: Thanks Dan, I checked it out though and nothing was there. I had to use euluis's method.. or else I am just doing something wrong with the formatting when I initially schedule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using Emacs 24.3.1 and Org-mode version 7.9.3f.

Pressing `C-c C-d` (or `C-c C-s`) and then typing in the mini-buffer a date and time period plus "+1w" (or "++1w") will result in the repeater part being ignored.

Since it didn't worked, I then go to the created DEADLINE or SCHEDULED and place the repeater:

```
DEADLINE: <2015-09-15 9:00AM-11:00AM ++1w>
```

Answer (score -1):

This post is a wee bit old, but just in case.

And Maybe I am not doing this right, but it always works for me.

I always do a : before Scheduled or Deadline

eg. `:SCHEDULED: <2019-07-06 9:00AM +1w>`

I also think you should only do 1x + as in my example.

I am GNU Emacs 25.3.1

Comment: How does this answers the OP's question? Please explain why you are placing colons before `SCHEDULED` and `DEADLINE`. Read about differences between `+`, `++`, and `.+` for recurring tasks.